# Javascript doesn't work correctly when css class is used more than once?

Tags: javascript, css, vertical-alignment

Previously, I asked how to center align an image (w/ dynamic width) within a div and someone replied with this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/WDzx4/6/

It's working correctly. However, when I try using the same class for another image, the other image is no longer vertically centered:

http://jsfiddle.net/b4Bbd/

You see, now, the 50x50 black image is slightly higher than it should be. I noticed that only the first image gets aligned correctly. If I add other images with a different width and height (using the same class) after that, they will be misaligned.

Could somebody help me find the problem as I'm not really familiar with javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the JavaScript to do everything for all matching elements, instead of calculating the height for one and applying to all:

```
$('div.container_img img').each(function() {
    var $img = $(this);
    var h = $img.height();
    $img.css('margin-top', +h / -2 + "px");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/timothyclifford/b4Bbd/7/